# Style specific parts of a form (HTML & CSS)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to style specific parts of my form, but I've been unsuccessful with selectors like `label[for="gender:"]` (I.e. to add more space for the radio buttons). I don't want to add a fieldset (I have one around the form as a whole), or create a special class or ID, I want to know how to style specific parts of forms without adding unnecessary syntax.

I've used the "Gender" label as an example, along with the radio buttons (which I do want to style), but I'm really asking for some help more generally about using selectors to style particular parts of forms.

Here is my syntax, along with a link to my Trinket page which I'm currently using (this is mainly for learning & practice rather than for publishing). Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thanks!

```css
#Container {
   width:800px;
   height:auto;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   font-family: garamond, serif;
   font-size: 16px;
}

header {
   color: blue;
   font-size: 30pt;
   text-shadow: 16px 8px 16px grey;
}

#MainBody {
   margin-top: 15px;
   margin-bottom: 15px;
}

form {
    float: left;
}

img {
   float: right;
   height: auto;
   width: 25%;
   transform: translate(-400px, -300px);
}

.Sidebar {
   background-color: #f2f2f2;
   display: inline-block;
}

nav {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 10px;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
   text-decoration-color: #000;
}

a:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#button1, #button2, #button3, #button4, #button5 {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    padding: 8px;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px #888888;
    border-radius: 16px;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
}

#button1:hover, #button2:hover, #button3:hover, #button4:hover, #button5:hover {
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.30;
}

#button1a, #button2a, #button3a, #button4a {
    background-color: #4BC402;
    padding: 8px;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px #888888;
    border-radius: 16px;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
}

#button1a:hover, #button2a:hover, #button3a:hover, #button4a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.30;
}

.contactform {
    width: 800px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#contactmetext {
    font-size: 16px;
}



.message {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    font-family: garamond, serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}

footer {
   text-align: center;
   margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>The World's Strangest Facts</title>
<style>
<!--  Separated for a CSS snippet --> 
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <a name="homeend"></a>
<!-- Container Starts Here -->
  <div id="Container">
<!-- Header Section Starts Here -->
  <header>
    <div id="HeaderOne">
      <h1 style="text-align: center">StrangeNET</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="HeaderTwo">
      <h3 style="text-align: center">The World's Strangest Facts</h3>
    </div>
  </header>
<!-- Header Section Ends Here -->
  <hr />

<!-- Nav Menu Starts Here -->
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <button id="button1a"><li><a href="#homeend"><strong>Home</strong></a></li></button>
      <button id="button2a"><li><a href="#"><strong>About</strong></a></li></button>
      <button id="button3a"><li><a href="#contactend"><strong>Contact</strong></a></li></button>
      <button id="button4a"><li><a href="#"><strong>Disclaimer</strong></a></li></button>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <button id="button1"><li><a href="#"><strong>Sociopolitical</strong></a></li></button>
      <button id="button2"><li><a href="#"><strong>History</strong></a></li></button>
      <button id="button3"><li><a href="#"><strong>Earth & Nature</strong></a></li></button>
      <button id="button4"><li><a href="#"><strong>The Cosmos</strong></a></li></button>
      <button id="button5"><li><a href="#"><strong>Technology</strong></a></li></button>
    </ul>
  </nav>
<!-- Nav Menu Ends Here -->
  <hr />

<!-- Main Content Starts Here -->
  <div id="MainBody">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et legendos argumentum complectitur eam. Ipsum dicat ea mea. 
No augue quaerendum disputationi sed, nostrum ponderum id mei, no eos quaestio voluptaria adipiscing. 
Putant singulis an cum, cum lorem possim habemus in. Vix quaestio sapientem cotidieque at, an nec habeo evertitur, no soluta indoctum pri.
    </p>
    <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et legendos argumentum complectitur eam. Ipsum dicat ea mea. 
No augue quaerendum disputationi sed, nostrum ponderum id mei, no eos quaestio voluptaria adipiscing. 
Putant singulis an cum, cum lorem possim habemus in. Vix quaestio sapientem cotidieque at, an nec habeo evertitur, no soluta indoctum pri.
    </p>
    <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et legendos argumentum complectitur eam. Ipsum dicat ea mea. 
No augue quaerendum disputationi sed, nostrum ponderum id mei, no eos quaestio voluptaria adipiscing. 
Putant singulis an cum, cum lorem possim habemus in. Vix quaestio sapientem cotidieque at, an nec habeo evertitur, no soluta indoctum pri. 
    </p>
    <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et legendos argumentum complectitur eam. Ipsum dicat ea mea. 
No augue quaerendum disputationi sed, nostrum ponderum id mei, no eos quaestio voluptaria adipiscing. 
Putant singulis an cum, cum lorem possim habemus in. Vix quaestio sapientem cotidieque at, an nec habeo evertitur, no soluta indoctum pri.
    </p>
    <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et legendos argumentum complectitur eam. Ipsum dicat ea mea. 
No augue quaerendum disputationi sed, nostrum ponderum id mei, no eos quaestio voluptaria adipiscing. 
Putant singulis an cum, cum lorem possim habemus in. Vix quaestio sapientem cotidieque at, an nec habeo evertitur, no soluta indoctum pri.
    </p>
  </div>
<!-- Main Content Ends Here -->

<!-- Contact Form Starts Here -->
  <aside>
    <div class="Sidebar">
      <form>
      <fieldset class="contactform">
      <h3 id="contactmetext">Contact Me</h3>
      <a name="contactend"></a>
      
        <legend><strong>Personal Information</strong></legend>
        
        <label>First Name:</label><br />
        <input name="firstname" type="text" /><br />
        
        <label>Last Name:</label><br />
        <input name="lastname" type="text" /><br />
        
        <label>Email:</label><br />
        <input name="email" type="email" /><br />
        
        <label>Gender:</label><br />
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br />
        
        <label for="msg">Message</label><br />
        <textarea class="message">Enter your message here...</textarea><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="submit" />
        <img src="contactme.jpg" alt="Postik Note">
        </fieldset>
      </form>
      <!-- Relative image address changed for Trinket only -->
    </div>
  </aside>
<!-- Contact Form Ends Here -->
  <hr />

<!-- Footer Starts Here -->
  <footer>
    <span>Mathew J. M. | 2018 ©</span>
  </footer>
<!-- Footer Ends Here -->
  </div>
<!-- Container Ends Here -->
</body>
</html>
```

https://trinket.io/html/b369625bd5

Comment: This is exactly what `fieldset` is for, grouping related fields. Another suggested use for `fieldset` is to encapsulate groups of radio buttons. You should also be adding `label` to "male" and "female". Don't be afraid of a little extra markup if it adds semantic meaning to your document. You may find it even helps with screen readers etc.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I'll add those labels to 'male' and 'female'. I haven't added another 'fieldset' tag around the radio buttons because it draws another box around them.

Comment: I've added and answer which should help demonstrate a few selectors and hopefully show why a nested `fieldset` isn't an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to reframe this a little. You mention you want to avoid "uneccesary syntax". I would argue your `br` tags are exactly that. They are pretty much semantically meaningless, give you nothing to style against and force the break. Let say for wider screens you wanted to display the label and element on the same line for wide screens but separate lines for narrow screens, you can't with the `br` tags.

So lets take out the uneccesary `br` tags and add some meaningful `fieldset` tags.

```css
/*Added Style*/

/*Make Labels Block Elements > is child selector*/
.contactform > label
{
    display:block;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}

/*Reset styling of nested fieldsets*/
.contactform fieldset
{
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}

/*Add some margin to the nestes labels, but only if they follow a radio button*/
/* + is the adjacent sibling selector */
.contactform fieldset input[type='radio'] + label
{
   margin-left:2px;
   margin-right: 20px;
}

/*END ADDED STYLES*/

form {
    float: left;
}

img {
   float: right;
   height: auto;
   width: 25%;
   transform: translate(-400px, -300px);
}

.Sidebar {
   background-color: #f2f2f2;
   display: inline-block;
}


a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
   text-decoration-color: #000;
}

a:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
}


.contactform {
    width: 800px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#contactmetext {
    font-size: 16px;
}



.message {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    font-family: garamond, serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
 

<!-- Contact Form Starts Here -->
  <aside>
    <div class="Sidebar">
      <form>
      <fieldset class="contactform">
      <h3 id="contactmetext">Contact Me</h3>
      <a name="contactend"></a>
      
        <legend><strong>Personal Information</strong></legend>
       
        <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
        <input name="firstname" id="firstname" type="text" />
        
        <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
        <input name="lastname" id="lastname" type="text" />
        
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input name="email" id="email" type="email" />
        
        
        <label>Gender:</label>
        <fieldset>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="gender_male"> <label for="gender_male">Male</label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="gender_female"> <label for="gender_female">Female</label>
        </fieldset>
        
        <label for="msg">Message</label><br />
        <textarea class="message" id="mdg">Enter your message here...</textarea><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="submit" />
        <img src="contactme.jpg" alt="Postik Note">
        </fieldset>
      </form>
      <!-- Relative image address changed for Trinket only -->
    </div>
  </aside>
<!-- Contact Form Ends Here -->
```

Some things to note. I've added ids to the form elements and `for` attributes to label. As your labels didn't have the `for` attribute your `label[for="gender:"]` selector did not work. Explicitly associating form elements with their labels adds functionality. Clicking a label for a text field will now bring focus to that field, clicking the label for a radio button or checkbox will check that element. It provides advantages in accessibility.

I didn't want to alter your markup too much, but one option to consider would be to use

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Gender:</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="gender_male"> <label for="gender_male">Male</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="gender_female"> <label for="gender_female">Female</label>
</fieldset>
```

You'd need to tweak the styling there a bit more.

For a little more info on the combinators I've used, see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#Combinators

One final tidbit of advice: get to know the browser developer tools. F12 in most browsers. The will enable you to see what styles are being applies to what elements and enable you to experiment with them in the browser. Just as importantly, they will show you what styles are being overridden and by what. This can help resolve specificity issues.

Comment: I really appreciate this, Jon. You've solved more than one question I had with this answer. You're a star.

Comment: Glad to help. Your next mission, should you choose to accept it, is to replace the `hr` tags. I find them only slightly more useful than `br`. Hints: look at top and bottom borders and the `::before` and `::after` [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)

Comment: Jon, thanks for providing additional info. I've taken on board all of your advice and I'm currently in the process of changing my code accordingly. Just one question, using a 'fieldset' tag for the gender radio buttons adds another box around those buttons within yet another fieldset box. I didn't really want another box for the radio buttons, hence me not using the fieldset a second time. What would you suggest I do (allowing me to group them together while avoiding 'br' tags)?

I will also have a look at my 'hr' tags after sorting the form out. :-)

Comment: Update: I have kept the additional fieldset tags you suggested. I've also added top and bottom margins of 10px to add additional space between the box and the outer fieldset (the form as a whole). 

I have also reduced the size of the form as a whole to 400px.

Comment: One last question, when you deleted the name="comment" & replaced it with an ID for the comment textarea, was there a reason for that?

Is it the 'name' that links the fields to their labels or is it the ID that you've assigned to them? I will definitely look at the link you posted above tomorrow (it's 2:40am).

Comment: Actually if you look at the code you posted, there is no `name` attribute (might be something to do with it being close to 3am for you!). When it comes to `name` vs `id`, `name` is generally used server side to collect the value, while `id` is used client side and is what the  `for` attribute is associated with. `id` is also used as a "hook" for CSS, javascript and internal links within a page.

Answer (score 1):

One way to style your gender buttons is by taking advantage of the attribute you set:

```
input[name='gender'] { 
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/dnwc0b4p/4/

For generic advice, I can understand not wanting to use classes or ID's, but getting used to them will benefit you greatly in the long run (e.g. [BEM naming convention](http://getbem.com/introduction/)).

[image: BEM image]

Classes are how we organize our HTML in ways that humans can understand and not computers.

Comment: Thanks Joseph. I have used IDs and classes many times in the past. I just wanted to reduce the need for extra syntax in this case, as I know that we're able to style forms with different types of attribute selectors, like the following: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you really used `label[for="gender:"]` as a selector, the reason is obvious: The `name` of the input is `gender` , not `gender:`, so your selector should be `label[for="gender"]`

Comment: I tried both before posting, Johannes. I was trying to add padding between the gender title (before the radio buttons) and the 'email' field above. It's still not separating the e-mail field from the 'gender' title coming immediately before the radio buttons.

Comment: I have also tried using the input[type="radio"] selector to add padding in the way I described above, but was unsuccessful. If I want to make the text red for example, it does work. I'm just unable to add the padding to separate out the elements within the form.

Comment: I have also tried the line-height property to add more space between the "Gender:" title and the "Email" field above along with the male/female radio buttons below it, but was still unsuccessful.